# How can I crop an included .pgf image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, crop

I have inserted using `\input` a `.pgf` image but I have a lot of white space between the image and the caption. I would like to crop the image so that I can reduce the white space. Is there any way I can crop a pgf image? Or reduce bring closer the caption?

```
\begin{figure}[!h]  
    \centering
     \fbox{
    \makebox[\textwidth]{\scalebox{0.4}{\input{test.pgf}}}
     }
    \caption{This is the caption.}

    \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Option 1 -- edit `.pgf` image

If you look near the start of the `.pgf` file you'll probably see something like (see example file at bottom of answer)

```
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{3.2in}{2.1in}}%
\pgfusepath{use as bounding box, clip}%
```

You can modify the `\pgfpathrectangle` to modify the bounding box. The `\pgfpointorigin` is (0pt,0pt). So for example, if you want to crop off 0.1in off both the top and bottom of the figure, modify the first line to

```
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0.1in}}{\pgfqpoint{3.2in}{2in}}%
```

## Option 2 -- `adjustbox`

You can use the features of the `adjustbox` package, which allows you to use `trim` and `clip` for the content in an `adjustbox` environment, similar to what you'd do with `\includegraphics`, e.g.

```
\begin{adjustbox}{clip,trim=1cm 2cm 3cm 4cm}
...
\end{adjustbox}
```

The four lengths for `trim` specifies the clipping done from the left, bottom, right, and top, respectively.

An example is below. I first ran the Python code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.random.rand(20))
ax.set_title('Cropping!')
fig.set_size_inches((3.5,2))
fig.savefig('demo.pgf',bbox_inches='tight')
```

And then the LaTeX code below produces this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}    
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{clip,trim=1cm 0cm 0cm 0.4cm,max width=\textwidth}
\input{demo.pgf}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

The content of `demo.pgf` is as follows:

```
%% Creator: Matplotlib, PGF backend
%%
%% To include the figure in your LaTeX document, write
%%   \input{<filename>.pgf}
%%
%% Make sure the required packages are loaded in your preamble
%%   \usepackage{pgf}
%%
%% Figures using additional raster images can only be included by \input if
%% they are in the same directory as the main LaTeX file. For loading figures
%% from other directories you can use the `import` package
%%   \usepackage{import}
%% and then include the figures with
%%   \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pgf}
%%
%% Matplotlib used the following preamble
%%   \usepackage{fontspec}
%%   \setmainfont{Bitstream Vera Serif}
%%   \setsansfont{Bitstream Vera Sans}
%%   \setmonofont{Bitstream Vera Sans Mono}
%%
\begingroup%
\makeatletter%
\begin{pgfpicture}%
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{3.277300in}{2.136040in}}%
\pgfusepath{use as bounding box, clip}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{1.000000,1.000000,1.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.000000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{1.000000,1.000000,1.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.277300in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.277300in}{2.136040in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{2.136040in}}%
\pgfpathclose%
\pgfusepath{fill}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{1.000000,1.000000,1.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.000000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.000000}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.376435in}{0.289968in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.088935in}{0.289968in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.088935in}{1.839968in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.376435in}{1.839968in}}%
\pgfpathclose%
\pgfusepath{fill}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfqpoint{0.376435in}{0.289968in}}{\pgfqpoint{2.712500in}{1.550000in}} %
\pgfusepath{clip}%
\pgfsetrectcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\pgfsetlinewidth{1.003750pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,1.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.376435in}{0.751682in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.512060in}{1.773703in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.647685in}{1.794826in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.783310in}{0.293527in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.918935in}{1.567596in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{1.054560in}{0.492625in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{1.190185in}{0.737764in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{1.325810in}{1.432323in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{1.461435in}{0.693324in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{1.597060in}{0.382698in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{1.732685in}{1.549752in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{1.868310in}{0.703512in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.003935in}{0.575388in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.139560in}{0.856688in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.275185in}{0.615278in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.410810in}{0.857337in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.546435in}{1.737982in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.682060in}{0.787242in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.817685in}{1.042006in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.953310in}{1.328030in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetrectcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\pgfsetlinewidth{1.003750pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{3.088935in}{0.289968in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.088935in}{1.839968in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetrectcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\pgfsetlinewidth{1.003750pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.376435in}{1.839968in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.088935in}{1.839968in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetrectcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\pgfsetlinewidth{1.003750pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.376435in}{0.289968in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.088935in}{0.289968in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetrectcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\pgfsetlinewidth{1.003750pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.376435in}{0.289968in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.376435in}{1.839968in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.055556in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.055556in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{0.376435in}{0.289968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.055556in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.055556in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{0.376435in}{1.839968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgftext[x=0.376435in,y=0.234413in,,top]{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 0}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.055556in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.055556in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{1.054560in}{0.289968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.055556in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.055556in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{1.054560in}{1.839968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgftext[x=1.054560in,y=0.234413in,,top]{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 5}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.055556in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.055556in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{1.732685in}{0.289968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.055556in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.055556in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{1.732685in}{1.839968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgftext[x=1.732685in,y=0.234413in,,top]{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 10}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.055556in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.055556in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{2.410810in}{0.289968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.055556in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.055556in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{2.410810in}{1.839968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgftext[x=2.410810in,y=0.234413in,,top]{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 15}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.055556in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.055556in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{3.088935in}{0.289968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.055556in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.055556in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{3.088935in}{1.839968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgftext[x=3.088935in,y=0.234413in,,top]{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 20}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.055556in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.055556in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{0.376435in}{0.289968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{-0.055556in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-0.055556in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{3.088935in}{0.289968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgftext[x=0.320879in,y=0.289968in,right,]{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 0.0}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.055556in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.055556in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{0.376435in}{0.599968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{-0.055556in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-0.055556in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{3.088935in}{0.599968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgftext[x=0.320879in,y=0.599968in,right,]{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 0.2}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.055556in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.055556in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{0.376435in}{0.909968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{-0.055556in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-0.055556in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{3.088935in}{0.909968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgftext[x=0.320879in,y=0.909968in,right,]{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 0.4}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.055556in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.055556in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{0.376435in}{1.219968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{-0.055556in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-0.055556in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{3.088935in}{1.219968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgftext[x=0.320879in,y=1.219968in,right,]{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 0.6}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.055556in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.055556in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{0.376435in}{1.529968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{-0.055556in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-0.055556in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{3.088935in}{1.529968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgftext[x=0.320879in,y=1.529968in,right,]{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 0.8}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.055556in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.055556in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{0.376435in}{1.839968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.501875pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{-0.055556in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-0.055556in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{3.088935in}{1.839968in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgftext[x=0.320879in,y=1.839968in,right,]{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 1.0}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgftext[x=1.732685in,y=1.909413in,,base]{\sffamily\fontsize{12.000000}{14.400000}\selectfont Cropping!}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfpicture}%
\makeatother%
\endgroup%
```

Comment: Where did you get the `.pgf` file from, by the way? Looks like it is badly made, considering the too large bounding box.

Comment: Actually is produced by a Python backend matploltib library

Comment: @GM `adjustbox` seems to work fine (see updated answer), I would try looking into what causes the large bounding box of the `.pgf` image though. (And personally I would make sure that the image generated by `matplotlib` has the correct size before inserting it into a document, so you don't have to scale the graphic.)

Comment: yes I was wondering if there was a way to crop the plot directly from the .pgf file but so far your answer seems the best solution

Comment: @GM Well, you can also edit the `.pgf` file (I can write something about that in my answer), but I meant seeing looking at the `matplotlib` side of things. There is really a lot of whitespace in your screenshot. Did you use `bbox_inches='tight'` as in my example?

Comment: I have saved it from the GUI so I did not. Your answer is perfect, I'll wait a couple of days and then I'll will accept it. Thanks a lot!